# Swift - how to fill size_t from C API via pointer

Tags: c, swift

I have a C API with

```
void Fill(size_t * val){
   *val = 15;
}
```

How can I call this method from Swift 3 and fill the internal class variable `var number`? Also, what type should it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the C header file in Xcode and select "Navigate->Jump to Generated Interface" from the Xcode menu then you'll see that the
function is imported to Swift as

```
public func Fill(_ val: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>!)
```

You call it from Swift by passing the address of an initialized
variable with `&` as inout expression, compare ["Interacting with C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17):

> Mutable Pointers
>
> When a function is declared as taking an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>`
>   argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - ...
> - An in-out expression that contains a mutable variable, property, or subscript reference of type `Type`, which is passed as a pointer to the address of the mutable value.
> - ...

In your case:

```
var myval = 0 // Type is `Int`
Fill(&myval)
```

But Swift defines `size_t` as well as

```
public typealias size_t = Int
```

therefore you can (even better) define the variable as

```
var myval: size_t = 0
```

which would then also compile on other platforms which might define
`size_t` differently.

Comment: Just one small nitpick: Since Swift has gone open-source, depending on the platform `size_t` might have a different type. It's always a good idea to check the concrete type of `size_t` before using it on the Swift side. Other than that, nice answer :)

Comment: @PedroCastilho: Yes, but "Jump to Generated Interface" would always show the concrete type, and the compiler would complain if you pass an incompatible variable (since Swift does no implicit type conversions).

Comment: @PedroCastilho: Updated answer to meet your concern, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to find what is the actual primitive type of `size_t` on your platform. Then, you can use [this table](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13) to find out what you'll need to use as this function's type. For instance, supposing `size_t` is a `#define` alias for `unsigned long`, the Swift signature for this function will be:

```swift
func Fill(_ val: UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedLong>!)
```

Since Objective-C is a strict superset of C, you can add C files to your project [the same way you would add Objective-C files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html): Create a bridging header and import the functions you want to use in it.

Once you've created a bridging header and imported the appropriate header file, you should be able to call `Fill` from Swift code with no issue. You should be able to use it as follows:

```swift
import Foundation

class SomeClass {
    var number: CUnsignedLong = 0

    func someMethod() {
        Fill(&number)
    }
}
```